# website shows incorrect server in some browsers after dns change

Tags: domain-name-system, cache

Ive recently transferred a domain to a new registrar and pointed it to a new server in the A records. Some computers show the correct server but scarily some of them show the old one. I don't think its a browser caching problem as even computers that have never visited the site before show the old page.

I've checked the dns propagation using a few online checkers and they seem to show the correct ip.

What kind of things might cause this behaviour? and what might i be able to do to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

"Recently" is a fuzzy term.  If the TTL on the old records was 86400 then you can expect DNS resolvers to take up to 24 hours to expire that record.  If "recently" means "within the last day" then everything is probably working as expected.

Because you also changed registrar, there are records other than the A record that might be cached such as your NS records and the glue at the parent.  These records often have even longer TTLs of two days or a week or even 10 days.

Some DNS resolvers cache records for longer than the TTL allows.  Whatever the Baidu Spider uses is an example of this.  I have seen them hitting old IP addresses three weeks after the TTL should have expired.  If the DNS resolver you are using does this, you could be stuck using the old site for a long time unless you change the DNS resolver you use.

You can check what records are cached and how long they have left before they expire at a specific DNS resolver by using `dig`.  This is an example checking Google's public DNS resolvers:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21902
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        18820   IN  A   93.184.216.119

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct  3 12:45:19 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45
```

The number in the answer section after the domain name is how long this resolver will continue to cache this result for.  You can also check the NS records:

```
$ dig @8.8.4.4 example.com NS

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> @8.8.4.4 example.com NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60519
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        6121    IN  NS  b.iana-servers.net.
example.com.        6121    IN  NS  a.iana-servers.net.

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct  3 12:48:19 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77
```

Answer (score 0):

DNS caching. Bad programming - so some browsers cache the old page a lot longer than you planned. The new server being "bad" in that it does not handle IMS (If Modified SInce) requests properly although the browser asks correctly.

Basically that is it. You have to check on those machines, but it runs down to either some DNS along the way still caching (some do that longer than your TTL) or the browser not asking the server. Or the server saying the page has not changed due to bad timestamps on the file system.